# What is the role of Application module in zend skeleton?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, acl

I have a project in hand that is going to have some five for more modules.
Each module is going to be used for one the departments in our organization.
They may interact with each other, but not necessary. 
Say finance, inventory, staff, etc.
So application is going to be sort of Business suite.

Question: In zend framework 2, the skeleton comes with an Application module.
Shall I look at it a global module that hold some common sections. like Applications layout wrapper for common layouts, for ACL controller and Auth controller, etc.

Is this some how the role for Application module? 
I appreciate any feed back.
Thanks

Comment: In our organization, we renamed the Application Module to Common module. This is where we place reusable services/models etc.

Comment: We have a Core module where we keep all the shared services/models. Then we use the Application module for the external user facing website and we add an Admin module for showing stuffs reserved to the applicatins owners

Comment: In project that I'm working on Application module is used to store commands that interact with model in another module via command bus.

Comment: Thanks every one. Your answers really helped.